# Can't build in launchpad, missing dependencies

Tags: compiling, launchpad

I have a bunch of .so libraries that can not build.

```
   dh_shlibdeps
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: cannot find library libnode.so needed by debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/android-messages (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/share/android-messages/debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages:/usr/share/android-messages/debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/lib/')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libgtk-3.so.0 needed by debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/android-messages (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/share/android-messages/debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages:/usr/share/android-messages/debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/lib/')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libgdk-3.so.0 needed by debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/android-messages (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/share/android-messages/debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages:/usr/share/android-messages/debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/lib/')
```

And the list goes on.

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libgtk-3.so.0 needed by debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/android-messages (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/share/android-messages:/usr/share/android-messages/lib/')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libgdk-3.so.0 needed by debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/android-messages (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/share/android-messages:/usr/share/android-messages/lib/')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot find library libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 needed by debian/android-messages/usr/share/android-messages/android-messages (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64' abi: '0201003e00000000'; RPATH: '/usr/share/android-messages:/usr/share/android-messages/lib/')
```

How do I fix this in my Rules file?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a mobile library with an x64 depend,  Specify your target architecture and see if it builds.

Comment: @RobotHumans how do I do that?

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I have similar problem.